# How to properly union with set

Tags: python, python-2.7, for-loop, set, union

I understand that any python set `union` with empty set would result in itself. But some strange behave I detect when `union` is inside of a for loop.

### looks good

```
num= set([2,3,4])
emp= set()
print num|emp
>>>set([2, 3, 4])
```

### confused

```
s = set()
inp = ["dr101-mr99","mr99-out00","dr101-out00","scout1-scout2","scout3-    scout1","scout1-scout4","scout4-sscout","sscout-super"]
for ele in inp:
  r = set(ele.split("-"))
  print r
  s.union(r)
print s
 >>>set(['mr99', 'dr101'])
    set(['out00', 'mr99'])
    set(['out00', 'dr101'])
    set(['scout1', 'scout2'])
    set(['scout1', 'scout3'])
    set(['scout4', 'scout1'])
    set(['scout4', 'sscout'])
    set(['super', 'sscout'])
    set([])
```

anyone could tell me why the last set s is empty?
is the output supposed to be every unique element in the set?

Comment: [`set.union`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set.union) **returns a new set**, so each time you're only adding the latest `ele` to the original (empty) set

Comment: thanks jonrsharpe, your comment is very helpful!

Comment: In this example, one could also use `s.add(r)`.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

`s.union(r)` is a **new** set with elements from both `s` and `r`.<sup>[reference](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html#set-objects)</sup> You need to change

```
s.union(r)
```

to

```
s = s.union(r)
```

or, use [`set.update`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set.update).

Comment: Or use [`set.update`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set.update), rather than creating a new set each time